# Schedule tasks in smallest interval: Algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, greedy

> Given a char array representing tasks CPU need to do. It contains
>   capital letters A to Z where different letters represent different
>   tasks.Tasks could be done without original order. Each task could be
>   done in one interval. For each interval, CPU could finish one task or
>   just be idle.
>
> However, there is a non-negative cooling interval n that means between
>   two same tasks, there must be at least n intervals that CPU are doing
>   different tasks or just be idle.
>
> You need to return the least number of intervals the CPU will take to
>   finish all the given tasks. (source: https://leetcode.com/problems/task-scheduler/#/description)

My code:

```
def least_interval(tasks, n)
  calculate_smallest_interval(tasks, n, 0, 0)
end

def calculate_smallest_interval(tasks, n, index, occupied_task_count, cool_down = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0})
  return 0 if tasks.empty?
  index = 0 if index == tasks.length && !tasks.empty? # reset to the front
  cool_down.each_key do |k|
    cool_down[k] -= 1
    occupied_task_count -= 1 if cool_down[k] < 0 
  end

  curr_task = tasks[index]
  if cool_down[curr_task] > 0
    calculate_smallest_interval(tasks, n, index + 1, occupied_task_count, cool_down)
  elsif occupied_task_count == tasks.length
    # idle period
    # don't increment index here because reconsider curr element
    1 + calculate_smallest_interval(tasks, n, index, occupied_task_count, cool_down)
  else
    cool_down[curr_task] = n # set the cooldown timer
    occupied_task_count = 1 # increment number of tasks in hash
    1 + calculate_smallest_interval(tasks[0...index] + tasks[index + 1..-1], n, index, occupied_task_count, cool_down)
  end
end
```

Caveat:
I understand now that the insight of this problem is that you always want to take the task that has the highest remaining number of instances pending & isn't cooling down to get the best result. However, I'm still interested in understanding where my code is wrong otherwise in approach (since my output is far smaller than the optimal result).

Explanation:

I have a hash table that keeps track of all relevant tasks cooling down. I also have an index variable that increments to keep track of current task -- if current task is available, keep it.

For a large tasks array and high n value, my output is significantly lower than the optimal output (so I know I'm wrong). Here's a smaller but demonstrative input/output combo:

```
IN: tasks = ['A','A','A','B','B','B'], n = 2 
Correct output: 8 
Mine: 7
```

Could someone tell me where they see a logical error in reasoning?

Comment: is this line correct `occupied_task_count = 1 # increment number of tasks in hash`? Your comment says it increments, but the code just resets to 1

Comment: Also, small thing but on `index = 0 if index == tasks.length && !tasks.empty? # reset to the front` you don't need the `&& !tasks.empty?` because the line before it returned if `tasks.empty?`, so you won't execute this second line if it's empty

Comment: You say, "...my output is significantly lower than the optimal output...". How do you know what the "optimal output" is? What I really want to know is whether there is an algorithm that produces an optimal solution.

Comment: @CarySwoveland with leetcode (the site the problem is from) when you have an account you can paste your solution into their editor and can run it against a single input or submit it to run through a variety of input from the community and it shows you a comparison of how your algorithm did against others or if you algorithm produced an incorrect result. It's an interview practice question site. So when Sunny pastes their code into the editor, the site says that answer is 8 and theirs is returning 7. (so "optimal output" = "what the site says")